# spaces and dual monitor: separate setup for each monitor?

Tags: macos, display, spaces, mission-control

I have two monitors and I would like to handle the virtual spaces separately on each. I.e. changing the space on one monitor shouldn't change the space on the other. (I wonder why this isn't even the default because it seems to me like it makes more sense.)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But I would love being proved wrong.

Comment: "(I wonder why this isn't even the default because it seems to me like it makes more sense.)" It defeats the purpose of spaces: to have configurations of multiple windows which you can alternate between

Answer (score 1):

It's not the exact answer you were looking for in the Mac OS but it is an alternative.

You can try TotalSpaces at http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/

It's been the only thing close to what you are looking for.

Comment: And one more objection I had to upgrading from Snow Leopard is removed.  Excellent!  I do find it Ironic, though, that I had to use a third-party virtual desktop plugin for so many versions before Apple included it, and now I need to go back to using one...

Answer (score 0):

On Mavericks, you can go to System Preferences -> Mission Control and check "Displays have separate spaces." This will accomplish what you want to do.